# Location of files specified within Django url patterns

Tags: django, apache, centos, redhat

I have been tasked to upgrade some very old code made in `Django 1.0`. I am not the admin on the server and my company's IT department is not always helpful  when it comes to linux, so I have to fix this myself.

The code has the following lines in it:

```
# Service Views linked URLs
urlpatterns += patterns('myservicename.views.service',
    url(r'^apptopleveldirectory/servicesdirectory/(?P<datatype>\w+)_transporter.php$', 'service', name="service"))
```

I have changed the names of the variables, but the file `*_transporter.php` is not under the `/var/www/` directory. I have tried to find it recursively, both as a file and as a symlink. However, if I make a call to it in the browser, e.g. `www.myservicename.com/apptopleveldirectory/servicesdirectory/json_transporter.php`

... it returns a `200` status message, which should be the case when the file has received the call successfully.

I want to understand what's happening here and if there's any other place than the web root where the URL pattern files should be placed.

Comment: A url does not resolve to a static file. It defines which view will be invoked when a certain url is requested. You need to find the view processing the request to that url to understand what it does.

Comment: No. There are no static files here at all, and no PHP files either. That code is intercepting the request for that PHP file and instead running the Python code in myservicename./vews.py, specifically the function "service".

Comment: That solved the problem. Could one of you please explain this in an answer, so I can accept it as the correct answer?